# Android title bar removal

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I have to add to a layout to hide the titlebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445999/what-do-i-have-to-add-to-a-layout-to-hide-the-titlebar)

How do I remove the title below the battery, time bar from showing up?

Not sure the terminology for that bar, but on this picture it is the "Nested XML Layout" bar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Janusz, didn't see that before.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Add the `android:theme` property to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: Refer to this for more information http://stackoverflow.com/q/2591036/346309

Comment: I used this, but afterword my application content disappeared, even thought the GUI is there. Note that I am filling my GUI using DB-manager java class, i.e. reading the content from a DB. what should I do ?

Comment: HI its removing icon only...its not removing title bar... Min SDK version for my app is 7.

Answer (score 19):

Use this on in Java file before `setContentView()`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Use this AndroidManifest file

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: What do you mean to use this AndroidManifest file ? wher to add this code for fullscrean?