# Remove only the title bar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

i just tried to remove the title bar from my project but it also removes the bottom bar that i use it for option menu to display there. Is there any way that i can to remove only the title bar?

thanks

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446373/android-title-bar-removal

Answer (score 1):

> @Override
>       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
> ```
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     // remove title
>     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
> }
> ```

add this in your onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Use    this  in  ur  java  code

```
requestWindowfeatures(window.Features_NoTitle);
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on your answer to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

add line in manifiest application section

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

this will remove title bar from your application

Comment: It should be without the fullscreen part

Comment: Yes you are right but i have used same that's why suggest same code