# How to hide the title bar for of android app?

Tags: android, android-activity

A have a problem
I want to hide title bar from activity from activity (without xml editing), but always get an error

I tried to use advices in few articles:
[Android title bar removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446373/android-title-bar-removal)
[How to hide app title in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862528/how-to-hide-app-title-in-android)
[Make full screen activity](http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-make-activity-as-fullscreen-removing-title-bar-or-action-bar/)

But it isn't led me to expected result. What i'm doing wrong?

IMG:http://i57.tinypic.com/wj6ud4.png

```
12-19 14:09:21.679      848-848/com.example.switchoff.test_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.switchoff.test_app/com.example.switchoff.test_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.getDecorToolbar(WindowDecorActionBar.java:248)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.init(WindowDecorActionBar.java:201)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.<init>(WindowDecorActionBar.java:176)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.createSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:156)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:123)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onTitleChanged(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:467)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onTitleChanged(ActionBarActivity.java:176)
            at android.app.Activity.onPostCreate(Activity.java:1000)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1142)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2042)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`getActionBar().hide();`

or 
`getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Answer (score 3):

you need not add :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

I have just added :

```
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,                                
                                               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Then in my style.xml, I have below :

```
....
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/logo</item>
</style>
```

this is working for me, hopes this helps you too...

Answer (score 2):

In Activity Use  `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before  `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);`
or

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

or For `ACTIONBAR` Use `getActionBar().hide();`

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide()
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Please add a plain-English explanation.