# Android Theme NoTitleBar & Fullscreen with Status Bar

Tags: android, webview, manifest

I have developed an phonegap app for Android. I had following attribute in manifest.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

And I figured out that when any `<input />` element was getting focus, the footer on the WebView (as it was of position:fixed) was getting up above with the soft keyboard. I found a fix for it by re-writing the manifest with the same attribute as follows.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But then another problem is there, the app has full screen and status bar is shown but it feels like the app initial part is under status bar. I read on other posts people trying to hide status bar setting this attribute but I don't want to hide the status bar but tell the android WebView not to shift or move any content inside it.

Is there alternative of **Fullscreen** to tell WebView not to shift or move content if it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

from: [How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to control that in the manifest file, by adding these attribute to the activity element:

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified"

or maybe

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

what ever you find suitable to you.
See [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) documentation for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your hmtl files to prevent shifting or autofocus.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

I had the same problem and this buttoned it up in short order.