# hiding the title bar in preference screen (android)

Tags: android

I am trying to hide the title bar on my Preference Screen but the usual `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Isn't working out, any suggestions?

My code is:

For my manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".prefs"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mittereder.rockpaper.PREFS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Logcat:

```
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mittereder.rockpaper/com.mittereder.rockpaper.prefs}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:228)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3144)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at com.mittereder.rockpaper.prefs.onCreate(prefs.java:22)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
08-10 00:08:07.502: E/AndroidRuntime(24457):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You might have missed "></activity>" or "/>" in the activity tag while u edited it. Please verify it... :)

Comment: ? i think its just tabbed over a little :)

Comment: For the more information check this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme/2591311#2591311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.myPreferences);

    }
```

in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyPreferencesActivity"  
                  android:label="@string/app_name"  
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: I tried that and my app crashed, i posted the logcat in my edit

Comment: post log when App is Crashing

Comment: Don't call setContentView() before requestFeature(). call setContentView() it after requestFeature()

Comment: use       `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);` instead of         `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: so like: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

Comment: im still getting the same crash

Comment: put android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: NOT WORKING (at least for 2.1 target) for any preference screens inside. The titlebar will open again. Anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You have set Theme for your activity in android manifest as follows...

```
<activity android:name=".Login" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

Please verify your activity tag after editing it.

Comment: i put android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" works like a charm <3 thank you!