# removing the activity name from the final app layout - android

Tags: android, android-activity, xml-namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

when I was running my app on my device or on the emulator, I can see the activity name on the top of the screen, like MainActivity or Hello World or whatever, and I'd like to remove it, but I don't know how. Should I write something in the xml file or something?

Comment: You can find a few different approaches here: [How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

Answer (score 2):

Activity titlebar (because that's what you are refering to) can be hidden either from Manifest, by adding proper theme to Activity declaration:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

or from code, by calling

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in Activity's `onCreate()`