# Remove android default action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

i remove the action bar by
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
however, when the app starts, the action bar appears in a very short time before it executes the above statement.
how can I make it totally disappear?
thank

Comment: Try selecting a theme in the Manifest, see the second answer here: [How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

Comment: On a side note: it's called an title bar, not an action bar. [Action bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) is a design pattern/window feature that's present in most newer Android apps.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I've noticed that if you set the theme in the AndroidManifest, it seems to get rid of that short time where you can see the action bar. So, try adding this to your manifest:

```
<android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Just add it to your `application` tag to apply it app-wide.

Comment: With so many answers, yours worked like a charm! Thanks. UPVOTED!

Comment: the bad thing is that it removes all theme styles

Comment: I getting an AndroidRunTimeException  : Unable to start Activity

Answer (score 15):

You can set it as a no title bar theme in the activity's xml in the AndroidManifest

```
    <activity 
        android:name=".AnActivity"
        android:label="@string/a_string"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
```

Comment: to add Theme.NoTitleBar in application is remove all the page theme effects. If you want to remove the action on First screen add the android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar". Save the theme for remaining pages.