# Replace TitleBar Default on Vertical View with Tab Titles

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

Been checking this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370719/remove-android-default-action-bar), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme). But It did resolve my problem I wanted to replace the default title and icon with Title Tabs.

```
        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
        // parent.
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

I been experimenting some codes from the links above, but I didn't get what I want.
The horizontal view is quite okay, but for the vertical view, it looks like the tabs are creating another title bar layer. which is not the same with the horizontal view. Guide me on this. Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't resolve this yet, but I guess I can't  put the tabs in the actionbar once it is in the vertical view, but if it is in horizontal view it goes directly to the actionbar section. My basis are from other applications with this scenario also.