# How to create Android application without ActionBar using new theme in API9?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar

I need to create application wihtout actionbar. I will try to explain how I create application(maybe I am missing some steps).

1.I am intentionally not choosing "Holo Light with Dark Action Bar" option. I thought this make application without action bar.
[image]
2.Leaving next page as default:
[image]
3.Leaving next page as default:
[image]
4.On the next page, it becomes interesting. Blank Activity's description says that it creates a new blank activity an action bar. On Empty Activity's description: Creates a new empty activity. So I choose Empty activity

[image]

5.Leaving next page as default.

Result:As usually, application was created with ActionBar.

[image]
[image]

Tried this solution:[getActionBar().hide();](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14167949/2255924). In this solution, ActionBar is hiden after some milliseconds.

**Tried to use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in AndroidManifest.xml->application tag. But in this solution, application uses old theme.**

[image]

**My question: how to create Android application without ActionBar using new theme and leaving StatusBar enabled?**

PS. I remember, about one year ago, in Eclipse, applications were created without ActionBar. Then we added it manually

Comment: try this in manifest file: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: Just change `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity` with  `public class MainActivity extends Activity` or change it from manifest

Comment: The android:theme may not have worked due to your minimum application target.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10318745/3033053)

Comment: @BatuhanC MainActivity.java is like this as default: public class MainActivity extends Activity

Comment: @user3819810, if I use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen". Application is using old theme as I showed in screenshot

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/YOURTHEME.NoTitleBar"

Comment: @user3819810, I tried like this android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleBar". But it is giving this error: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/
 AppTheme.NoTitleBar').

Comment: @Spurdow, MainActivity extending Activity by default

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable action bar permanently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently)

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot, I have tried to use that solution. But it requires API11, Technical Task requires me to create application for API9+

Comment: Your Question solution is already Answered . Do google it before posting Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this right after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in the `onCreate` method of your activity(s):

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Make sure you put this BEFORE `this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);` to avoid crashes

Comment: Thanks you for your answer and valuable time. But this option disabling status bar(notification bar).

Answer (score 1):

When your project is started you can use public activity extends Activity instead of using ActionBarActivity this will also remove the action bar or there is another way

```
    <android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

or you can see these links they might help

[How to hide action bar before activity is created, and then show it again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again)

[Remove android default action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370719/remove-android-default-action-bar)

Comment: As I described in question ("Tried to use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in AndroidManifest.xml->application tag. But in this solution, application uses old theme."), this makes App use old theme

Comment: picpaste.com/Screenshot_2014-08-21-11-58-43-AA6TRgPY.png

Comment: @JoeRichard you want your app to like this pic right without action bar ?

Comment: @JoeRichard I applied the code given in first link in my answer and there was not action bar. try this 

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

Comment: you misunderstood me. I dont need for old theme(as shown in screenshot). How to remove ActionBar at the same time using new theme like this?

Comment: @JoeRichard I thought you were asking for removing the actionBar from your activity. Sorry mate then you have to keep searching but if you want to remove action bar from your app then I have written the code above.

Comment: Sorry, buddy. I agree with you. I should have state question correctly. Thank you for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code and change as per your requirement:

**Update :**

styles.xml :

```
 <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
</style>
```

These will remove actionbar and keeps your theme as it is .

**Note** : Here i have tested using Theme.Holo . you can use yours.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name=".GridViewExample"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It gives you activity without ActionBar. 
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: As I described in question ("Tried to use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in AndroidManifest.xml->application tag. But in this solution, application uses old theme."), this makes App use old theme

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programatically:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Or you can do it via your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

**EDIT :**

If your app uses any other theme use corresponding theme name E.g. For White theme `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`

Comment: this method is working. because of this:android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" app will use old theme. How to use this method by using new theme? is it possible?

Comment: If your app uses any other theme use corresponding theme name E.g. For White theme @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen

Comment: Tried like this android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen". It is giving this error: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/
 Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen').

Comment: @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen requires API13+. I need API9+