# Remove just the TitleBar from an ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbaractivity

The red rectangle (The bar with the title of the activity) it is what I want to remove (see the picture):
http://subefotos.com/ver/?8e6468bdbc19b0864d5090fa79e54120o.jpg

What I have in my code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, OnItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
} }
```

I can remove all the bar, including the HOME-STATISTIC-CLASSIFICATION, but I don't want to remove this.

I think that what I want to do it is impossible if we take into account this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html
Although if somebody knows how can be done, please post it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370719/remove-android-default-action-bar Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently

Comment: @Eran I can't find in this links what I am looking for. I think that is impossible to do what I want to do. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I could not understand why you want to use ActionBar and then try to make it Disappear. Just use TabHostActivity I think you can Achieve what you desire.. ( I am replying by looking your snap )