# How to remove action bar in tab view android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, pager

I have an action bar with tabs, lay out looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cySGd.png

As you can see there are 2 sections in action bar (one where icon and app name is printed, and another where tabs are placed)

How can I remove portion of action bar where title and icon of application is displayed completely so that only tabs are shown on the top of screen

Comment: cannot post image until I have 10 rep

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want to show your Activity in Full Screen. you can achieve that with that code

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}}
```

You can refer these [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android) it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want to disable your action bar.
Use this in Application tag of your manifest file.

```
  <android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

If your problem doesn't resolve so feel free to ask me.

You can use this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370719/remove-android-default-action-bar),
It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For disable the action bar completely for your application use this in your manifest file under application tag or for particular use under activity tag.

< android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >