# How to hide the title bar in a particular activity style by overriding the Application Style

Tags: android, themes, titlebar

I want to override a application theme on a particular activity, but its not working for me

This is code on my Manifest.xml:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        android:name="com.ssdevnet.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
    android:name="com.ssdevnet.Home"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

And this is what i used in style:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

and its still not working on Android 2.3.6 or below but working on 3 and above.

Also i tried to use this on the oncreate method on class file for that particular page:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);// Removes title bar
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar
```

but its not working on my phone running Android 2.3.6 but its working on Emulator running Jellybean and i need something that works on all the versions.

And I need to know some things as i am a newbie to android:
Can we define a Global theme, and override that theme on some activities? if yes, what method can we use?

Or we have to define theme for every activity if we are targeting activities instead of app?

I also want to learn about deploying the custom themes in the app.. if there are some good tutorials and references please share.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2627952/1693859)

Comment: Already tried that.. doesn't fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using setTheme(..) before calling setContentView(...) and super.oncreate() and it should work fine in the Activity.

Check out the [Android developer's site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for more information.