# How to remove the white screen while my app loads?

Tags: android

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is a really simple app, and it is almost as it was when it generated.

I also used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14115809/1344937 to remove the title.

When I open the app, a white screen appears for less than a second and then the blue screen comes. How can I change that?

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid I saw this qustion, but the answers didn't help me...

Comment: but it helped me and now there is no white screen in my app

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One quick, easy way is to make your launch screen Translucent.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.taxeeta.BookingExperience"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT!! I was trying to do a slpash screen and create activity  etc.. and then just this small line :)

Comment: This solution didn't help me because using `final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` will return null when the Theme is translucent

Comment: its an awesome solution

Comment: Making the launch screen `Transculent` results late opening of the app untill performing `DBOperations` done in `Main Activity`

Comment: Hello +1 for the answer but one more way i cme to know by giving this `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>` in Manifest Applicatin theme its not showing .

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" did not work for me, any suggestion ?