# How to remove initial screen Android?

Tags: android

I make an application that its min SDK is API 14. However, when first launching the application, the app shows a screen with action bar contains application icon and application name, then after awhile, it goes to my home(main) layout.

How can I disable that screen? I don't know what the screen is called. Here is some structures of my `manifest` file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/myTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="..."
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`myTheme`:

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_app</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.App</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.App</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.App</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.App</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.App</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_app</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_app</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.App</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme

Comment: Hi Izmaki, I haven't tested the answers from that post but I believe that all the answers refer to hide the title bar not hiding/removing screen that show the application icon & name before showing the home/main activity..

Comment: is it your login page of your application???

Comment: Of course not.. The screen appears when first launching the application before showing the home/main screen..

Comment: I think in your first activity you are setting one View (.xml) and onCreate() method you are redirecting to another activity. is it so?

Comment: You can also try reducing the amount of processing you do in the activity before in onCreate and onStart

Comment: Andrain: No it isn't.. It is automatically created..
RayBritton: Yes I know, but can I just simply remove that screen?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android:theme="@style/myTheme"` with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"` in the `application` tag in manifest and the first white screen won't appear. It will directly open your home activity

Comment: I don't think I will choose your solution if it works because I want to use my own theme..

Comment: Try including `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` in your theme then, this is what is basically there in the `@android:style/Theme.Translucent` theme

Comment: Hi Apoorv, still the screen with my application icon and name appears before the home screen..

Comment: In the `style` you are creating try to use parent `@android:style/Theme.Translucent`