# How to remove "initial" screen Android?

Tags: android

Calling back my old question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154986/how-to-remove-initial-screen-android)

I have problem that my app always load this "initial" screen when user first open my app:

[image: Before load]

So after it loads, it load my first screen.

My first screen should be (and, I think, must be) this one.

[image: After load]

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Msd"
```

and below is my `Theme.msd`(generated from [here](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)) :

```
<style name="Theme.Msd" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_msd</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Msd</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Msd</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Msd</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Msd</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Msd</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_msd</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_msd</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Msd</item>
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole content of `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

This "initial" screen is the result of Android loading your app. Startup of your app takes its time, especially if you perform a lot of work in the beginning, so you can never completely solve this. There will always be some measure of a delay when starting your app. But there are a few things you can do to improve the situation:

1. **Find the culprit:** If this initial white screen is displayed for an unusually long period of time (maybe even seconds) then most likely you are blocking the UI `Thread` somewhere. Are you implementing a custom `Application`? If yes then you should know that any work performed in `onCreate()` will add to that initial startup delay. The same goes for `onCreate()` in your `Activity` but the one in your `Application` is much more important when it comes to startup performance.
2. **Use a transparent `Activity`:** You can mitigate the problem in some measure by making it seem as if your app hasn't started yet. For that purpose you can style your main `Activity` to be transparent and hide the `ActionBar` initially. In that case you need to explicitly add a background to the layout of your `Activity` otherwise it will remain transparent once the loading has finished. You can show the `ActionBar` again in `onCreate()` of your `Activity` or even later in the life cycle if you want. To make an `Activity` Transparent use a style such as this:

```
<style name="Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

If you are not using any support `ActionBar` libraries you can also use Androids default transparent style `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`. Just apply on of those styles to your main `Activity` like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Transparent">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Hi Xaver, it works perfectly if I change the `windowIsTranslucent`, but I need to add custom animation while loading next activity, since the default animation is gone..

Comment: After some inspections, when I tried to press Home button, the app blinks my phone Home screen, then the app exit. Do you have any advise?