# Remove Title Bar from all the Layouts

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am beginner to the android

to hide the title bar in all layouts i was selected that in Graphical Layout
"App Theme"(A star Marked one)----> All---->NO Title Bar Option.

When i selected that my total Graphical Layout is turn into BLACK COLOUR

How to solve it? please help me

Comment: Take a look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme

Comment: At Layout creation it self Title Bar should be removed sir/madam. Actually I was went through this link before and followed the above procedure. I didn't get answer

Comment: solved this problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

Add the last line in manifest

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```