# Another way of hiding title bar

Tags: android

I am using this code for hiding the title bar. Is there any other way of doing the same?

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme

With XML like you want

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your manifest to use a theme that doesn't use a titlebar

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

or you can specify a new style as [done in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14115809/1758149):

Answer (score 1):

For Api level 14 and above you can use

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

else for below api if you have to add v7 support library change Activity to ActionBarActivity

then you can just call

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

This will give you full screen with notification bar