# Cannot seem to remove Action bar programmatically or in XML

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-xml

I've followed the plethora of helpful and thorough instructions around SO and the internet in general regarding removing `ActionBar`s in an `Activity`. I've tried to do so via the `onCreate()` method and XML but my `ActionBar` has irritatingly remarkable resilience.

I tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme) in my `onCreate()` method and the notification bar disappeared, but the `ActionBar` did not.

I have, of course, tried appending `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` and quite a few other `.NoActionBar` and `.NoTitleBar` themes in the XML to the first `RelativeLayout` (is this the right place to put it? It's the highest level automatically present), to no effect.

Any ideas as to why these methods have failed?

Comment: Did you change the theme on the all Style.xml files ? values/style.xml , values-v11/style.xml and etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the nuclear option. Extend your `Activity` as

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    ...

}
```

instead of

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    ...

}
```

Comment: This is not a solution

Answer (score 1):

In your `onCreate` method, execute this code:

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: I thought he said he already tried everything ... he *must* have tried this, right ?

Comment: If he would have tried _everything_, this question would not be asked :-) @ZygoteInit

Comment: Well, what I mean is that `getActionBar().hide()` is the first and most trivial thing anybody would do :)

Comment: You'd be surprised... :-) @Zygotelnit. Anyway, upvoted your answer.