# How to remove the title bar from Android app

Tags: android, android-layout

How to remove the title bar from my app.?

I tried by making changes in manifest file by adding "NoTitleBar" at the end of theme and i also followed the answer given in this question

"[How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)"

But none of them worked for me.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add in your activity before you set view in oncreate function.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

It is because your activity is extending ActionBarActivity. You could replace by extending Activity for your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: sure sir, just replacing ActionBarActivity with Activity worked fine to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file you can find a tag `<application`
That tag contains `android:theme` attribute, it must be something like `"@style/AppTheme"`. Open the file `styles.xml`. 
Find a tag `style name="AppTheme"` and change its `parent` attribute to be `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

In my case it is

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

To hide the title bar on the `preview mode` click on the button next to the orientation switcher button, that must open a popup where you can choose a style. Choose one with `NoActionBar`, for example `DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar`