# How can I delete the Blue tape from the top of the activity in a new project in android?

Tags: android

Perhaps my question is simple, But I do not know the Its response. When I create a new project in android studio, I see a Blue tape from the  top of the activity and my program name written on that.

How can I delete the Blue tape from the  top of the activity in a new project in android?

Comment: thats called an actionBar.You sir need to clear your basics and terminology first.

Comment: Did you just forget to paste your question in google before pasting as Question? There are already great QA for the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatical way

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Alternate way Inside maifest file in activity tag use

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

  OR

  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

put this theme in your manifest file in application Tag

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"