# How can I hide the title Bar from the activity_main layout

Tags: android

How can I hide the title Bar from the `activity_main` layout? I have android studio 1.3.1 and I used the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` within the  activity tag but when I see the `activity_main` again I see the title Bar or the same action Bar again. How can I hide it?

Comment: Do you want to hide the entire ActionBar or just display an empty title ?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/2627952/5202007

Answer (score 0):

Put this code below the AppTheme in your styles.xml file whixh is in values directory.

```html
    <style name="MyThemeNoTitle" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

And in your Manifest.xml file put theme tag to your activity as,

```html
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyThemeNoTitle">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define this theme with no ActionBar and which is also supported in all Android versions:

```
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

After you can apply this theme as the theme of the entire application or just for your MainActivity in the manifest with the attribute `android:theme`