# Best way to stay in Immersive Full-Screen Mode when changing the Activity?

Tags: android, android-immersive

I would like to use the Immersive Full-Screen Mode in my app.

I have no problem entering the mode, but when I start the next `Activity` it is gone. 
I fixed this by creating my own `Activity`-class which extends `AppCompatActivity` and overloads `onCreate(...)` with

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

All my other `Activities` now extend this class.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to hide title if so go to this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme

Answer (score 0):

Setting the flags that you are using (less View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE) the bars begins to hide and show dynamically. Now you must set this behavior in the method onResume.

If you need add any behavior to this functionality go to this link:

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html