# Phonegap upper grey bar is still showing (android)

Tags: android, cordova

**I have read the other questions but nothing helped**. A bar like [this one](https://cdn.infoq.com/statics_s2_20160622-0236/resource/news/2013/06/fries-android-html-javascript/en/resources/fries-1.png) but with no label, icon and grey instead of black still appears on top of my phonegap app running in the phonegap tester on my phone and listening on my ip.

Here is my code:

- My page is simply an iframe with no style applied.
- ***config.xml*** outside of www folder contains this (sorry but for some reason I was not able to format code to the block):

  `... 
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  ...
  <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
          <supports-screens
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:smallScreens="true" />
          <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
              <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
              </activity>
          </application>
      </gap:config-file>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>`
- The **config.xml** **inside** the www folder contains the same properties as well.

Does anyone have any idea on what the problem might be? I need this to run in complete absence of any extra headers. I want to run this simply with the iframe...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xamarin, try

```
RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
```

and if you're using Java, it should be something like

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in your OnCreate() method.

I recently dealt with this in C# and I sourced the Java solution from here [How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

Comment: It's phonegap, sorry, forgot to mention. It's in the tags though (cordova)

EDIT: actually I did not forget to mention, it was there right at the beginning :)