# FullScreen Layout doesn't work on Android

Tags: java, android

I have an `activity_login.xml` with a `FrameLayout` in `Android Studio`, which doesn't appear in fullscreen mode with this configuration:

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/LoginScreenTheme.TranslucentBar" >
</activity>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<style name="LoginScreenTheme.TranslucentBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

The `Toolbar` is still appearing in the `Layout`.

Comment: Change to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't do anything and today when I started my project, the activity was in fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your activity Layout, most likely there is Toolbar view that AndroidStudio generated for you. If that does not work add to the style:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify onCreateView() as below

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the Toolbar/ActionBar you don't need to do anything special at all. Just keep everything as default and go to the styles.xml and change the AppTheme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar and also make sure that your activity extends AppCompactActivity. It always works for me. Hope it will help you as well. And if you also wants to remove the StatusBar then follow @EKN solution above ;)