# Still having issues removing android title bar

Tags: android

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);        

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Using the above code only causes app to crash - also

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Does not work

Comment: This is in your `onCreate` right? Are you using the support libraries?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14115809/2372784

Answer (score 0):

try to define a custom theme like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

and set the theme as your activity theme in manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity.File"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
```

it works on my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```