# Is it possible to have tabs without a toolbar when developing an app for Android with material design?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and I want to make an app that is almost immersive. Does android let you remove the toolbar and use only the tabs?

Comment: yes, ActionBar/Toolbar is optional ... why didn't just tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` is optional. You can remove it anytime from your layout.

If you don't want to use `Toolbar` then just use `TabLayout` in your layout XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#ff4938"/>
```

Hope this will help~