# How can I remove the title bar from an Android app?

Tags: android

I am trying to remove the title bar like this: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/2591311/3364266

Answer (score 1):

try this in manifest file :

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define your application style in styles.xml file, and not in individual layout files. Here's an example from one of my projects:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android manifest.xl when u adding activity
add this code

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.apply this theme to remove whole title bar in your style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

than apply ti your activity like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

**2. try this for full screen activity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);
    }
```

**3. also try this**

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can try this in your activity before setContentView:

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

//set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_here);
```