# requestFeature() must be called before adding content in fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I want to show fragment in activity without no title bar. i also have added request window without title bar before inflating the views. this is not happening and it is showing exception as

```
requestFeature() must be called before adding content
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:318)
    at com.wishkart.wishkart.dialogFragment.HomeProductDialogFragment.onCreateView(HomeProductDialogFragment.java:30)
```

My fragment code is given as:

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_product_popup, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Try moving it to the onCreate on the activity before setContentView is called.

Comment: i want to show a fragment without title bar

Comment: A fragment must be contained inside an Activity. The FEATURE_NO_TITLE  is part of the Window/Activity. Did you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that views have already been added when `SetContentView` is called which happens before `onCreateView` in the fragment. The solution is to ensure `FEATURE_NO_TITLE` is requested before the call to `setContentView`.

Inside the enclosing `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(
final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // Hide the Title bar of this activity screen
  getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  ...
}
```

You could also hide it inside the fragment like this:

```
 @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
  }
```

Or `getActivity().getActionBar()` if the support library is not being used.

Note: Call `show()` to restore the `ActionBar`.

But I would advise doing it from the `Activity` if you are going to do it in code.

But the most maintainable framework friendly way to hide the bar is to use a style rather than doing it in code:

[Hiding the `ActionBar` with a theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

Comment: In my activity i am showing many fragment but I want to hide title bar for one fragment and other will remain same.

Comment: Okay. The original post was asking about how to get rid of requestFeature error which I think I've answered...But see the other solution that I just added, hide() and show() can be called on the ActionBar from within the fragment.