# How to hide toolbar in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm really new on android and working on a small project using one of the google templates; the tabbed activity with tabs...is there a way to hide the title section (tabbedExample) and keep only the tabs?

[image]

styles.xml

```
  <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Manifiest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="c.example.jinzunza.tabstoolbars">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Write like this:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Answer (score 28):

You can simply hide the toolbar putting this in your activity, into the oncreate method:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: weird that `actionBar.hide()` doesn't work even though it's a method

Comment: that's because actionBar is not the same as supportActionBar, they are two different implementations inside Android SDK. the old one is actionBar, and the support library added supportActionBar besides all the other compatibility implementations for older Android Versions.

Answer (score 15):

**For Activity:**

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

**For Fragment in Java:**

```
((MainActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

**For Fragment in kotlin:**

```
(requireActivity() as MainActivity).supportActionBar!!.hide()
```

Answer (score 4):

set this theme in your styles.xml file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in your onCreate()

Or even simpler, set your theme to: `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`

The very similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

You should find more answers there.

Answer (score 1):

Use this on create method:

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

this helped me

```
supportActionBar?.hide();
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer differs from the others with an [edit].