# How does top part of the app calls. Android programming

Tags: android, kotlin

How does the top part of the app calls (which is green with text "calculator")? I want to make an app with different styles on each layout, but I do not know how to google it.
**Answer is found, it calls "app bar"**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is change the default sytle of the app in **style.xml** or in the activity with Java/Kotlin code. [This may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme).

After that you can add your custom app bar. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up) a little example from Android Developers Blog.

Hope this useful to you.