# Remove Default Title Bar

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I remove the top title bar that's default in an Android app?

[image]

The gray Hello, Android bar?

Comment: What do you want to do? Just remove it and have no title bar or replace it with your own custom title bar? Did you at least try googling it first because I just googled your title and it gave me a bunch of good results..

Comment: this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446373/android-title-bar-removal and potentially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445999/what-do-i-have-to-add-to-a-layout-to-hide-the-titlebar/2446087#2446087

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I didn't find anything right away. I suppose I would rather use a custom title bar than just remove it.

Comment: <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:screenOrientation ="portrait" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"> Throws and error. I am assuming because I cannot access theme twice? Is there a workaround? MyTheme.NoTitleBar does not work either

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Its very simple to remove the title bar Just, Add the android:theme property to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: `<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:screenOrientation ="portrait" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">` Throws and error. I am assuming because I cannot access theme twice? Is there a workaround? MyTheme.NoTitleBar does not work eithe

Comment: do you have that Theme installed in your device ?

Comment: MyTheme or Theme? Mytheme is linking to new background image

Comment: This information is indeed right when you are developing an app but what if I want to change that bar size and colour in EVERY app?
I am looking for the ROM parameters about this (I think)...

Answer (score 23):

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/xyz</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This was the solution to my ending problem.Thank you very much! But was not my original question so I cannot mark solution for others sake.

Comment: That's it... combining your theme with the native on... thanks

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Go into manifest file

Click the "Application" tab on the bottom (as shown)

Enter `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` (as shown)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

To do that I declared a style inheriting everything from my general style. This style disabled the default Android titleBar.

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Create a new style and add this style in your different views or add this code in the default style to disabled the titleBar for all windows!

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurs when you are using default inbuilt toolbar and your own custom toolbar. There are two method.

1) Navigate to Values/style.xml <---Base Application theme styles to-> and change your parent theme like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

2. Another method is to add theme attributes to your activity as in manifest file:

   android:theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 1):

And also several themes are available without the title bar. For e.g.`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` applies the respective theme without title bar

Answer (score 1):

For **Android Studio 2.2.2**, 2016

Replace in `app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` the parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` on `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

Example:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

inside AndroidManifest.xml I added the code =)