# Android Studio: How to avoid auto-creation of ActionBar/Toolbar in the app

Tags: android, android-studio

**This is in the design interface.**

[image]

**This is the emulator.**

[image]
The blue bar comes out of nowhere. I tried something like NoTitleBar, and the app just crashes. Someone help me Please!

Update my question. The extending to Activity does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Default Title Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561178/remove-default-title-bar)

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: no it is not a duplicate. The one you linked to is for titlebar. This question is for actionbar/toolbar

Answer (score 4):

Extend just `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` in your Java class and the toolbar would be gone.

And remove the code referencing toolbar from `onCreate()` (if any was generated) and anywhere else (if you manually added) after changing the extended class, else you may see errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried that but it doesn't work. See my update in the question.

Comment: It has to. If you are not extending AppCompatActivity, you'll have no toolbar automatically. If you still see it search for the word "toolbar" in your Java file and see of you have manually added the toolbar. Remove those limes of code and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

change your `theme` in `styles.xml` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` no extra code needed!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10659285)

Comment: @SHAZ It does. When he referred to blue bar he meant the toolbar "actionbar" and by default android has a darkActionBar when you choose one of the templates Android studio provides. Please before bashing on people get your facts together.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help. I've tried your method but the outcome is it changes the blue bar to a white one...Well, if the background is white,  it may look like it doesn't have the bar, but my background is grey. I wish I could post another picture but I can't because of the reputation stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly open the activity_main.xml then there will be somecode like this one

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

delete the above code from activity_main.xml

Now open the MainActivity.java and delete the below code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

after this your problem should be solved.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works! Thank you so much! I've tried many methods but I just ignored that this setting in the activity main.

Comment: dude you can just hit +1 button so that other can benefit from it.. because i also faced this problem and it took me 3 days to figure this out because when i googled it i found nothing about it so i myself have to figure it out.

Comment: Hey, of course I want to click like! But my reputation is like 6, only people with reputation over 15 can click like! Sorry for that, you did an amazing job! If I got more "reputation", I will come back and like! So, for now, what I can do is screaming out :" Somebody come here and Click like! This is the only useful answer for the problem!!!"

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

make sure you are not using `getActionbar()` or `getSupportedActionbar` in any activity that using this theme otherwise you will get `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above doesn't work then, create a new style in your Style.xml file

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml file, set your activity theme to the one you create :

```
<activity
        android:name=".Example"
        android:label="Example"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This was originally in my code, but I still have the bar.

Comment: there must be two xml files.. one will be content_example.xml and other will be activity_example.xml. Can you post code of both of those files?

Answer (score 0):

Well i had the same issue some time ago, and hiding it dynamically through code was the only solution that worked. In the onCreate() method do the following:-

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

This will definitely work.

Answer (score -1):

use theme with actionbar like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and in your activity use `getSupportActionbar().hide();` in `onCreate` before `setContentView()`