# How to create android game loading screen

Tags: android, android-activity, program-entry-point

When you start android app Main activity starts with white background and black header with your app name in left corner. Like [this](http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/7012/submenudemomainactivity.png)

How to wholly remove this (when app is started not to show this) and add custom loading progress bar or some logo to the screen?

Comment: It only looks like that because that's how you coded it.  Are yo saying that you want a different starting activity?

Comment: Yes, I know it looks like that because it is coded like that.
Yes I want different starting acrivity

Comment: To remove title bar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445999/what-do-i-have-to-add-to-a-layout-to-hide-the-titlebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me (since I don't have much load up on start actually I didn't need splash screen at all) is changing res/values/styles.xml :

```
<resources>
<color name="custom_theme_color">#000000</color>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" >
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

It just start with black screen witch goes to full screen (after 1-2 sec) when it is all loaded.
It looks very "profesional".

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a splash dialog with custom layout containing progress bar?

In your main activity do something like this

```
private SplashDialog mSplashDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    showSplashScreen();
    setContentView(R.layout.yourmainlayout);        
}

protected void removeSplashScreen() {
    if (mSplashDialog != null) {
        mSplashDialog.dismiss();
        mSplashDialog = null;
    }
}

protected void showSplashScreen() {
    mSplashDialog = new SplashDialog(this, R.style.splash_dialog);
    mSplashDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mSplashDialog.show();
}
```

Create custom dialog

```
public class SplashDialog extends Dialog {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    public SplashDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_dialog);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splash_progress);
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}
```

And add style to that will let dialog fill all screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="splash_dialog">
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

To change dialog's progress value call `mSplashDialog.setProgress(int progress)`.

When your data is loaded call `removeSplashScreen()`.

Comment: Thanks this was useful!
But still when I start application first it starts with [this](http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/7012/submenudemomainactivity.png) (it is there for very short time) and then it goes to splash screen.
How to fully remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for can be found here:

[how to change the splash screen](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=15)